# CSS id for selection and class for style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation

I'm writing a form with validation, and I want to highlight the text boxes when they're not properly filled. I added this CSS rule:

```
/*Styles for validation*/
.invalid {
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
```

The fields in my form have IDs, such as `#f1` for the first field, which have no CSS styling, but I'm using them to select the fields using jQuery. So when I detect an error I say:

```
$('#f1').addClass("invalid");
```

According to Firefox's inspector, the element now has the style #f1.invalid, however I don't see any of invalid's styling applied to the element. How can I get the behavior I'm looking for? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I lied, there is an inline style on my text fields, setting the width to 5ems, however removing it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: I think something else is going wrong... that looks like it should work

Comment: http://jsbin.com/oxipaj/1/edit works just fine... the issue is somewhere else

Comment: Looks like the problem is with specificity.

Check if that element has inline styles.
Any styles associated with an id.

Comment: if you prefer jsfiddle to jsbin:
http://jsfiddle.net/mmPpR/1/

Comment: That should not be a problem unless you have a selector that is setting the border : 0px somewhere in your HTML or CSS

Comment: You should really try to create a minimal test case for issues like this.  The code as described works fine.

Comment: I see that my scenario isn't cropping up in these isolated demos, so I'm sure I've screwed something up elsewhere. I'll keep poking at it. I don't believe I'm setting the border anywhere else, but you never know

Comment: @Nick in Chrome, you can right click > Inspect Element and see all the styles applied to it. That may help in your troubleshooting.

Comment: try removing other styles... or putting the .invalid style rule in a `<style>` element.  Perhaps your css is malformed

Comment: Perhaps you can post your HTML code? Maybe there is something we are missing. You don't have to post it all, just what is relevant.

Comment: If you're not using Chrome (and thus can't use @sachleen's suggestion) you should really use the Firefox extension Firebug (debugging in IE is only for the masochistic).  Either Chrome's built in CSS inspector or Firebug's will instantly tell you which rules are being applied to a given element, and which are being trumped by other styles, and that knowledge should make your problem *trivial* to solve.

Comment: @machineghost, Firefox has a very robust set of built in developer tools which negate the need for a plugin like Firebug. Regardless, the problem has been solved

Comment: While I welcome the Firefox team's attempt to catch up to Chrome, and I certainly don't want to start an argument over who's inspector is better ... let's just say there are still plenty of reasons for any serious web developer to use Firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with my CSS or my HTML. My FTP client hadn't been uploading my changes to the .css file. Beware the dangers of cached temporary files!

Answer (score 0):

A selector with a matching an *id* is stronger than a selector with a matching *class*. This means if you've a rule setting *border* for the element with the *id* `#f1` then the rule for the class isn't applied. To make the class one apply you need to tell it that it is even more important;

```
.invalid {
  border: 1px solid #FF0000 !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a rule setting the border for the F1 id, like I said, there's no style associated other than the built-in rendition for the text box. !important doesn't do the trick

Comment: @Nick .. Can you create a fiddle for the scenario you are talking about .. Also use !important as a last resort..

Comment: If the problem is specificity, _reorganize_ your css, use a class instead of an id, do _everything_ you can before using `!important`.

Comment: @Nick we can't help you if we can't reproduce the issue.. set up something reproducible we can work with or we're just guessing.

Comment: !important is a frequently misunderstood aspect of CSS (much like z-index; if I had a nickel for every `z-index: one bajillion` that does absolutely nothing ... but I digress).  As elclanrs suggested, you should not use !important, but rather instead should use a more specific rule.  I'm a big fan of the Darth Vader guide to CSS specificity, as it really makes the topic understandable.  Check out: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Comment: @machineghost I do agree that over reliance on `!important` is bad and in general it shouldn't be employed for normal styling. That said, however, I think for the case of error feedback it is okay and helpful to use.